# how many `<main>` main tag can be used in a html document / Page

Tags: html

how many main tags can be added to my html page. Is there any restriction to add more than one main tag(like one  per page)?

is this correct way of using main tag??

```
<body>
  <header></header>
  <aside></aside>
  <main>
    <section></section>
    <main>is this correct!!!</main>
  </main>
  <footer></footer>
```

Comment: According to the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html-main-element-20121217/#the-main-element): _Authors must not include more than one main element in a document._

Comment: Technically you could do that, browsers will parse it for you. But semantically it's a bad idea.

Comment: @Leo - _"MUST NOT - This phrase, or the phrase "SHALL NOT", mean that the definition is an absolute prohibition of the specification."_

Comment: @chipChocolate.py Yeah, I know. From spec's point of view it's forbidden. However, if you really did that, browsers wouldn't likely to throw errors. Anyway, my point is, even if browsers allow you to do so, it's a bad idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `main` element represents the main content of the body of a document or application. The main content area consists of content that is directly related to or expands upon the central topic of a document or central functionality of an application.

> **Authors must not include more than one main element in a document.** ([source](https://www.w3.org/TR/html50/grouping-content.html#the-main-element))

Authors must not include the main element as a child of an `article`, `aside`, `footer`, `header` or `nav` element.

Comment: Any references for this quote?

Comment: @Trix, its mentioned in the W3C schools site it self, Please find link for the same. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_main.asp#ezoic-pub-ad-placeholder-124

Comment: Thanks for the link, but you would better refer web pages from authoritative, official websites like [W3C (World Wide Web Consortium)](https://www.w3.org/). w3schools is not a good reference, though it helps you learn fast & easy

Comment: I have edited the source link to include documentation from w3.org instead of w3schools that include the same quote in the HTML5.0 specs. However, I have to mention that I can't find that quote or any similar text in the [HTML 5.1 specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/grouping-content.html#the-main-element)

Answer (score 2):

## once only

here's a great article on [HTML5 DOCTOR](http://html5doctor.com/the-main-element/).

> It should house the main content of a document or app. Its most important purpose is to "map ARIA’s landmark role main to an element in HTML."

It can’t be used as a descendant of an `<article>, <aside>, <footer>, <header>, or <nav>` element.

here's an example of typical usage.

```
<body>
<header role="banner"></header>
<main id="content" class="group" role="main">

<!-- main content -->

</main>
<footer role="contentinfo"></footer>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

> **It can't be more than once and should not be a descendent of any of these elements `<article>`, `<aside>`, `<footer>`, `<header>`, or `<nav>`.**

The `<main>` tag purpose is to specify a document main content. Therefore, it should be the `main` container as cleared from its semantics and it should be used once in an HTML document.

**Browser support:**
`<main>` tag has fairly good support in all modern browsers except the great IE

For more detail with example you can read it **[here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_main.asp)** (w3schools).

Comment: The element is not to be supported by standard browsers. They simply accept it is a html element. The tag is meant to be supported by readers and bots.

Comment: Sorry, one correction. Screen readers do not support the main tag itself, but they do support announcing a tag with `role=main`. And latest versions of Chrome and Firefox automatically add the role main to the main tag... So in a way some browser make the main tag work for screen readers.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is a bit confusing.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/main) states:

"A document mustn't have more than one < main > element that doesn't have the hidden attribute specified."

This was actually my idea: having more main's where only one is visible and the remaining hidden, so that an eventual navbar allows to switch 'pages'.

I think this is the reason why MDN says that, and it would be a very valid use case, although clashes with the W3C spec.

Comment: What's to stop you from just having multiple div's in the main? If they're all the main pages, then they can go there. `<main><div id="main_div1" style="display: none;">Hidden Div1</div><div id="main_div2">Visible div2</div></main>`

Comment: Agree, I would do it like you wrote too. Mine was just a comment on MDN statement, where instead of using div's as you described, the use different <main>'s with only one visible and the remaining hidden. I just wanted to highlight the confusion of the interpretation of the spec. Btw, Safari supports multiple <main>, no idea about other browsers

Comment: I submitted a bug ticket concerning the MDN entry: https://github.com/mdn/content/issues/3210

Comment: Also here is how I do best of both worlds: https://tritarget.org/Simple%20Router

Comment: As far as the W3C spec — any HTML spec version that was ever published at the W3C is now long out of date and should not be used for anything. Instead, the actual current HTML standard at https://html.spec.whatwg.org/ is the only spec that should be consulted or cited anywhere at this point. See also https://github.com/mdn/content/issues/3210